# Regular Expression Replace Time Value between Date-Time Format

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have an XML file with date-time formats looking like this:

```
<published>2019-01-03T23:54:00.000+10:00</published>
```

and this

```
<published>2019-01-07T14:22:00.001+10:00</published>
```

and so on, where the time value is 23:54:00.000 and 14:22:00.001.

How do I replace just the `time` value between the `<published></published>` tags with regular expressions? For example, I want to replace both time values with 03:00:00.000 so the first example becomes

```
<published>2019-01-03T03:00:00.000+10:00</published>
```

My aim is to use any existing tools/apps Notepad++ or websites since it is much faster, not any specific programming languages.

Comment: Something like this [`(?<=<published>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T)\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}(?=[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}<\/published>)`](https://regex101.com/r/hh0sgd/2)?

Comment: Should only datetimes within `published` tags match?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed your answer seems to be the most suitable so far, do you want to write an answer so I mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @henry000 what do you find lacking in the two current answers (mine and @potato's)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(<published>\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}T)\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{3}([^<]*<\/published>)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oMnzo4/3)**

Replace each match with `\103:00:00.000\2` i.e. Group 1 contents followed by `03:00:00.000` followed by Group 2 contents.

**Explanation:**

- `(<published>\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}T)` - matches `<published>` followed by 4 digits followed by `-` followed by 2 digits followed by `-` followed by 2 digits followed by the letter `T`. This sub-match is captured in Group 1
- `\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{3}` - matches time of the format `XX:XX:XX.XXX` where `X` is a digit.
- `([^<]*<\/published>)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `<` followed by `</published>`. This sub-match is captured in Group 2.

**Before Replace:**
[image]

**After Replace:**
[image]

Comment: Note that this may return false positives if the data contains other datetime values which shouldn't be matched.

Comment: This answer is good, but as @swalladge said, I have other tags like <updated> that I don't want to modify, I just want to modify what's in <published>.

Answer (score 1):

First, the obligatory warning to not try to parse xml/html with regex. It's fine if this is a once-off reformatting task and you have control over the data. A regex solution will not be very robust...

That out of the way, you will need a tool that can handle capture groups with regex, so you can match on the whole `published` tag and avoid false positives. A regex like this might do the trick (adjust the capture grouping as appropriate for your tool):

```
(\<published\>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT)\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d(\+\d\d:\d\d\<\/published\>)
```

Note that the above is a regex in PCRE format - [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0M2cMy/2). You may need to adjust to suit the format your tool uses.

In this regex, there are two capture groups, one before and one after the time you want to replace. An example string that you could use in the replace field of your chosen tool would be: `\103:00:00.000\2` (using `\1` syntax for backreferences).